# Assign value to datepicker in reactive forms

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in my project, and two of the inputs are date inputs, with a `datepicker` but when I try to assign them a value I get an error `TypeError: date.match is not a function`.

form.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.url[1].path
    this.dataService.getProject(this.id).subscribe((rps) => {
        this.agreementSumary = {
            agreementType: rps.agreement.agreementType,
            referenceNumber: rps.agreement.referenceNumber,
            isEffective: rps.agreement.isEffective,
            dateEffective: rps.agreement.dateEffective,
            dateExpiration: rps.agreement.dateExpiration
        }
        this.agreementEditFrm.controls["dateEffective"].setValue( new Date(this.agreementSumary["dateEffective"]))
        this.agreementEditFrm.controls["dateExpiration"].setValue( new Date(this.agreementSumary["dateExpiration"]))
    },
        error => console.log(error)
    )
}
```

The value that I get from my service are strings, and I'm parsing them because my input in my form is a `datepicker`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?